# Removing contents from Text widget

Tags: python, tkinter

In Tkinter, how can I remove the contents from Text Widget. In my program i have used it for displaying running log. I want to limit the number of lines it display i.e. after a particular line number limit is achieved, i want to remove the old contents in parallel. Below is the snippet of code which does content modification in Text Widget. As you can see, once the 25 lines have been inserted, I am using "delete" method to remove 1 line. But strangely after 25 lines have been displayed, it clears the whole widget and then on subsequent calls to this class, adds one line and after some time removes it. Can someone please help me fix this issue.

```
class TextRedirector(object):
    def __init__(self, widget, tag="stdout"):
        self.widget = widget
        self.tag = tag

    def write(self, str):
        global linecount
        linecount = linecount + 1
        self.widget.configure(state="normal")
        self.widget.insert("end", str, (self.tag,))
        self.widget.update()
        if linecount > 25:
             self.widget.delete('1.0', '2.0')
        self.widget.see('end')
        self.widget.configure(state="disabled")
```

Comment: it seems to me that `delete` should that integer arguments, but perhaps I'm just crazy ...

Comment: @mgilson: Delete takes indices which are represented as "line.column" (or tag names).

Comment: @BryanOakley -- Thanks for clearing that up for me.  I suppose the answer is "mgilson, you're just crazy".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears your `self.linecount` variable grows without bounds, and doesn't take into consideration that you are deleting some lines. So, once you have > 25 lines, every time `write` is called it will delete one line.

Are you aware you can attach a scrollbar to a text widget? That would allow virtually unlimited text, and let the user scroll back to see old data.

Comment: I have already used scroll bar in my text widget. But i don't want it to display 20,000 lines. I'll check linecount variable limit.

Comment: You were right, linecount variable was not considering line deletions. Also, i found that write command was called two times per line (one with data and other with \n).